# How to say "that many" or "that much" in French as in "It's not that much"?

Tags: grammaire, comparatifs, emphase

How to say "that many" or "that much" in French as in

- *It's not that much*
- *I don't eat that much*
- *There's not that many apples*

For "I don't eat that much", would you say

> Je ne mange pas à ce point.

or

> Je ne mange pas autant.

But when saying "I don't eat that many apples", would you say

> Je ne mange pas autant de pommes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Je ne mange pas tant (de pommes)
- **Je ne mange pas tant (de pommes) que ça**
- **Je ne mange pas autant (de pommes)**
- Je ne mange pas autant (de pommes) que ça
- Je ne mange pas à ce point

The bolded ones are the most common ones.

Answer (score 0):

"autant", definitely, in both of your sentences.